# Unable to install rpy2

Tags: r, python-3.6, rpy2

On mac 10.12.6, `pip install rpy2` is giving me "Failed building wheel for rpy2"

I tried the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23484836/2232265).  Any ideas what to look at next?

Here is the error log:

```
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rpy2
  Running setup.py clean for rpy2
Failed to build rpy2
Installing collected packages: rpy2
  Running setup.py install for rpy2 ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/me/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/c2/tn3m3j415fq7hhh4zwwqrphw0000gn/T/pip-build-v9hm43qh/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/c2/tn3m3j415fq7hhh4zwwqrphw0000gn/T/pip-1onyudah-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
    /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
    /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags

        Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
            include_dirs    = ['/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include']
            library_dirs    = ['/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib', '/usr/local/opt/readline/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib', '/usr/local/opt/readline/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/lib']
            libraries       = ['R', 'pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'icucore', 'm', 'iconv']
            extra_link_args = []

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/situation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2
    copying ./rpy/tests_rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/container.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/functional.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike
    copying ./rpy/rlike/indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_container.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_functional.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike/tests
    copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rlike/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Device.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_EmbeddedR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Sexp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpClosure.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpEnvironment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpExtPtr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpSymbol.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVectorNumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/conversion.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/environments.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/functions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/help.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/language.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/methods.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/numpy2ri.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/packages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/packages_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/pandas2ri.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/robject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    copying ./rpy/robjects/vectors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testArray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testDataFrame.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testEnvironment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFormula.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFunction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testHelp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testLanguage.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testMethods.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testNumpyConversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPackages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPandasConversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRObject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRobjects.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testVector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/dbplyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/dplyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/ggplot2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grdevices.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/test_dplyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tidyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_dplyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_ggplot2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_grdevices.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/packages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/interactive
    copying ./rpy/interactive/process_revents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/interactive
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/interactive/tests
    copying ./rpy/interactive/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/interactive/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/ggplot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython
    copying ./rpy/ipython/rmagic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython/tests
    copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython/tests
    copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/test_rmagic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy2/ipython/tests
    running build_clib
    building 'r_utils' library
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/rpy/rinterface
    clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -I./rpy/rinterface -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:24:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/Rdefines.h:36:
    /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/R_ext/Memory.h:48:17: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    int     R_gc_running();
                        ^
                         void
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:24:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/Rdefines.h:40:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/Rinternals.h:51:
    /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/R_ext/Rdynload.h:38:26: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    typedef void * (*DL_FUNC)();
                             ^
                              void
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:24:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/Rdefines.h:40:
    /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_1/lib/R/include/Rinternals.h:919:26: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    const char *R_curErrorBuf();
                             ^
                              void
    3 warnings generated.
    x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar rc build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/libr_utils.a build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
    unable to execute 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/me/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/c2/tn3m3j415fq7hhh4zwwqrphw0000gn/T/pip-build-v9hm43qh/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/c2/tn3m3j415fq7hhh4zwwqrphw0000gn/T/pip-1onyudah-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/c2/tn3m3j415fq7hhh4zwwqrphw0000gn/T/pip-build-v9hm43qh/rpy2/
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78855

Comment: You installed R via Homebrew. Can you uninstall it and install the official binary instead and then follow my instructions [here](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340)? Try the [easiest fix](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340#comment-38480254) first.

Comment: @cbrnr note that my error message does not mention `fopenmp` -- I found other similarities in that thread, but do you still think your instructions there would solve my problem?  If so, could you be more specific about which thing to try since there is a lot of chatter on that thread?

Comment: You're right. But as I've mentioned please try using the official R binary instead of the Homebrew one. Also, unless you installed the latest clang via Homebrew you will run into the `-fopenmp` issue.

Comment: Ah right -- I forgot to acknowledge that -- yes I did fully uninstall R and then installed the official R binary from CRAN but that did not seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

*The start of an answer, not yet working:*

[A/the rpy2 developer pointed](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340) me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299040/sourcecpp-does-not-work-after-updating-r-to-3-4-1).

I followed [the instructions here](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#after-3-4-0) (for R >= 3.4.0) resulting in a new directories `clang4` and `gfortran` in `/usr/local`.  I also set up the `~/.R/Makevars` file as suggested.  (There was no `~/.R` dir on my system previously).  Doing these things had no evident effect.

I'm guessing I'm missing something basic. Should I be re-installing R? Exporting some environment variables?